# Как найти наиболее часто встречающуюся пару значений?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм, в котором по колонкам разбросаны данные строкового типа.

Как найти наиболее часто встречающуюся пару строк?

Пример:

```
data={'1':['ball', 'pen', 'pencil', 'paper', 'mug',None,None,None,None],
      '2':['notebook', 'pen', 'computer', 'paper', 'desk',None,None,None,None],
      '3':['ball', 'notebook', 'pen','pencil', 'paper', 'mug',None,None,None],
      '4':['ball','notebook',None,None,None,None,None,None,None], 
      '5':['computer','ball', 'pen', 'pencil', 'paper', 'mug','notebook','pipe','tube']}
dat=pd.DataFrame(data)
dat
```

Задача получить на выходе значения 'pen' и 'paper'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверняка можно как-то проще, но я не нашёл другого способа "склеить" колонки датафрейма в один сплошной список:

```
pd.DataFrame(dat.values.flatten()).value_counts()
```

Вывод:

```
pen         4
paper       4
notebook    4
ball        4
pencil      3
mug         3
computer    2
tube        1
pipe        1
desk        1
dtype: int64
```

Но вообще тут наиболее часто (по 4 раза) встречаются 4 слова, а не 2.

**UPDATE:** переделал на сочетания из двух слов в каждом отдельном столбце

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

data={'1':['ball', 'pen', 'pencil', 'paper', 'mug',None,None,None,None],
      '2':['notebook', 'pen', 'computer', 'paper', 'desk',None,None,None,None],
      '3':['ball', 'notebook', 'pen','pencil', 'paper', 'mug',None,None,None],
      '4':['ball','notebook',None,None,None,None,None,None,None], 
      '5':['computer','ball', 'pen', 'pencil', 'paper', 'mug','notebook','pipe','tube']}
dat=pd.DataFrame(data)

counter = Counter()
dat.apply(lambda x: counter.update(combinations(x[~x.isna()].values, 2)))
print(counter.most_common(1))
```

Вывод:

```
[(('pen', 'paper'), 4)]
```

Если посмотреть все сочетания из `counter.most_common()`, то тут уже да, 4 раза только эти слова сочетаются, а остальные 3 раза и меньше.

```
[(('pen', 'paper'), 4), (('ball', 'pen'), 3), (('ball', 'pencil'), 3), ...
```

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что надо найти не наиболее частоту каждого отдельного слова, а комбинацию из двух слов

Comment: @GlT_2021 А, комбинацию внутри одного столбца?

Comment: Да в комбинацию внутри одного столбца, которая повторяется по всему датафрейму, смысл как в онлайн магазине, если каждый столбец это отдельная покупка, надо понять какие товары чаще всего заказывают вместе

Comment: @GlT_2021 Я сделал

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться методом [Series.mode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
In [39]: dat.stack().mode()
Out[39]:
0        ball
1    notebook
2       paper
3         pen
dtype: object
```